# How to mach subdomain to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subdomain

I want to map my abc.example.com to dashboard#abc without configuring subdomains. How can I do that? I am using Rails 3.2.14. Helps admired

I have a link as www.example.com/abc and my client wants to have it as abc.example.com

Answer (score 0):

We do this in Rails 4:

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints({ subdomain: "abc" })  do #-> abc.domain.com
    get "/", to: "dashboard#abc"
end
```

If `abc` is a namespace, you'll want to do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints({ subdomain: "abc" }) do
   namespace :abc, path: "" do
       root to: "dashboard#abc"
   end
end
```

---

In Rails 3, [you'll want to do this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3):

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints({ subdomain: "abc" }) do
  match '/' => 'dashboard#abc'
end
```